# Is it possible to approximate or bound this nonlinear mapping L h(x)?

Tags: approximation, nonlinear-optimization

I wanted to make sure whether the following approximation is possible.

I have a vector ${\bf{x}} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ where the elements of the vector $\bf{x}$ are random variables. There is a matrix $L \in {\mathbb{R}}^{N \times N}$ so that the vector $\bf{x}$ is transformed to another vector $y = L\bf{x}$.

Now I would like to make sure whether the following matrix $K$ could possibly exist, when a nonlinear "element-wise" mapping function $h(\cdot)$ is applied for each element of the vector $\bf{x}$ (i.e., $h({\bf{x}}) \in \mathbb{R}^N$ ):

$z = L \cdot h({\bf{x}}) \approx K \cdot \bf{x}$.

I consider $h(\cdot)$ as a bounded function (e.g., $tanh(\cdot)$) and $L$ as a Laplacian matrix for now.

If an approximation doesn't make sense, can anyone help me find a bound to compare $L$ and $K$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common problem to approximate a nonlinear map, such as $L\circ h$ here, by a linear one. Such problems come in two flavors:

1. You want approximation to be accurate for $x\approx x_0$. Then you use the derivative of $h$ at $x_0$ to build a linear approximation.
2. You want approximation to be accurate on some set. Suppose the set is finite (we can take a finite subset that captures its geometry well enough). Then you can fit a linear map to $Lh$ by minimizing the sum 
   $$\sum_i \|Lh(\mathbf x_i) - K\mathbf x_i\|^2\tag1$$
   over all matrices $K$. This is a standard [Least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) problem.

As for how accurate the fit will be: in case 1 there are remainder estimates in [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem); in case 2 the sum in (1) gives a general idea (especially if you divide by the number of points and take square root).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In eq. (1), if I want to find the matrix $K$ that minimizes the sum, can I just differentiate with respect to $K$? Is there any assumptions needed? Well... I am not good at this problem. Could you give me an advise how to find $K$? Or any hint (or example problems) that is related with eq. (1) ??

Comment: @Lee Yes, you can arrive at the equations for $K$ by differentiation. But this has been done already, and implemented in standard least squares solvers. The W jesus page to which I linked gives a starting point.